# Use Realm for ReactNative integration with existing apps, and ReactNative's page can't load normal

Tags: react-native, realm, react-native-ios

*Realm JS SDK Version: realm v2.21.1

*Node or React Native: node v11.5.0 & React Native v0.55.4 & npm v7.10.0

*Client OS & Version: mac os 10.13.6

I'm using the realm in my react native project, and this project is a integration with Existing Apps.I'm using node v7.10.0 install realm and using node v11.5.0 install other component.I went from native to react native page and back. When I go on the ReactNative page again，the page failed to load successfully.Please help me.

This is a demo of the operation video。[here](https://dailypractice.oss-cn-shanghai.aliyuncs.com/tmp/1.mp4)

NativeCode：

```
- (void)createButton {
    UIButton *btn = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(100, 100, 150, 50)];
    [btn setTitle:@"GoReactNative" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [btn addTarget:self action:@selector(handle:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [btn setTitleColor:[UIColor redColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [self.view addSubview:btn];
}

- (void)handle:(UIButton *)sender {
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:[RNViewController new] animated:YES];
}

# RNViewController.m
RCT_EXPORT_MODULE();
RCT_EXPORT_METHOD(back) {
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        UINavigationController *navController = (UINavigationController *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate].window.rootViewController;
        [navController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
    });
}

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    [self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:YES];
    NSURL *jsCodeLocation = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://localhost:8081/index.bundle?platform=ios"];

    RCTRootView *rootView =
    [[RCTRootView alloc] initWithBundleURL: jsCodeLocation
                            moduleName: @"demo"
                     initialProperties: nil
                         launchOptions: nil];
    self.view = rootView;
}
```

JSCode:

```
export default class App extends Component {
  _back() {
    NativeModules.RNViewController.back();
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <Text style={styles.welcome}>Welcome to React Native!</Text>
        <Text style={styles.instructions}>To get started, edit App.js</Text>
        <Text style={styles.instructions}>{instructions}</Text>
        <TouchableOpacity
          activeOpacity={0.5}
          onPress={() => this._back()}><Text>BackToNative</Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

[demo](https://dailypractice.oss-cn-shanghai.aliyuncs.com/tmp/demo.zip)

[demoWithNode_ModulesAndPods](https://dailypractice.oss-cn-shanghai.aliyuncs.com/tmp/demoWithPodAndModule.zip)

Comment: why need to write native code instead of Javascript ?

Comment: Please do not post images of your code, but your code itself

Comment: @AsbarAli This is a native old project that recently used ReactNative.

Comment: @dentemm I have edited it again, please check it.